# Initialize additional object in Django model instance and pass model instance

Tags: python, django

Some calculations became too complex to maintain inside my model, so I decided to move them out and break the code in several classes and modules.

There's a single class serving as a facade which I would like to have available in a model instance to pass data to it.

It is being constructed from model instance:

```py
class Calculator:

    def __init__(self, field1: date, field2: float):
        self.field1= field1
        self.field2 = field2

    @classmethod
    def from_django_model(cls, django_model_instance):
        field1 = django_model_instance.field1
        field2 = float(django_model_instance.field2)
```

Currently I call it inside each property on my model like so:

```py
class DjangoModel(models.Model):
    # initialize the calculator
    def calculator(self, group):
        return calculator.Calculator.from_django_model(self)

    # use it
    @cached_property
    def calculated_field(self):

        try:
            return self.calculator().calculation_method
        except AttributeError:
            return "Field not set!"
```

I feel this is not a good solution, since now on multiple methods I'm initializing the calculator object multiple times.

I would like to construct it once when the model is initialized and then pass it to the model instance.
I tried doing this with model manager, but the model instance is not available with it.